# IIS Rewrite very confusing

Tags: wcf, iis, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

concerning IIS Rewrites.

I want to change this url on my local IIS Instance

http://localhost/MySite/health?key=BczI5MyulpRLxI2kiJmIXwLOm78r3qr8z2gwcsYTGR4=&c

to redirect to this url:

http://localhost/MySite/Health.svc/BczI5MyulpRLxI2kiJmIXwLOm78r3qr8z2gwcsYTGR4=/c

As you can see I don't want the incoming request to use

```
Health.svc/BczI5MyulpRLxI2kiJmIXwLOm78r3qr8z2gwcsYTGR4=/c
```

instead to use

```
health?key=BczI5MyulpRLxI2kiJmIXwLOm78r3qr8z2gwcsYTGR4=&c
```

The Health.svc is the WCF endpoint name, so I just want /health with the key and filter parameter at the end as shown.

Whatever I put in my web config rewrite it still doesn't work. I am rather confused what bit of the url to put in, as the regex seems to be valid as I can test it in IIS and online regex validators.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="HealthRewrite" stopProcessing="true" enabled="true">
      <match url="MySite\/health\?key=([0-9a-zA-Z=]+)&amp;([a-z])" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="MySite/Health.svc/{R:1}/{R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

How can I get this to work? I have got the rewrite module installed as can see it in IIS an also can see the dll is registered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working with going to all sorts of sites as its not obvious at all.

They key seemed to put the conditions in and then a {QUERY_STRING} with regex which can then create the {C:1} and {C:2} groups that are pushed into the new rewrite

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="HealthRewrite" stopProcessing="true" enabled="true">
      <match url="^health" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="key=([0-9a-zA-Z=]+)&amp;([a-z])" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/MySite/Health.svc/{C:1}/{C:2}" appendQueryString="false"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I found it confusing knowing what url to match but with a few simplified tests of just ^health I could see more easily and play around with getting the query string parameters. I had to provide the Rewrite with the /MySite/ prefix which is confusing as the match didn't need that!

Comment: If you learn how to troubleshoot, it won't be confusing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match the value of the query string in IIS, you need to use {QUERY_STRING}. Here is a demo:

```
      <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Test">
                    <match url="(Service1)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(key)=(.*)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="Service1.svc/{C:2}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

This is my web.config.

This URL:

http://localhost/Service1?key=getdata

will redirect to this url:

http://localhost/Service1.svc/GetData

[image]

**For your last question, why add the MySite prefix? This is because the URL in the Rewrite URL will be used as the redirect URL. Notice that it uses back-references to preserve and rearrange the original URL pieces captured during pattern match. For Rewrite, all prefixes other than localhost must be provided in the Rewrite URL.**

Comment: Thanks for the details break down, much appreciated